# Understanding "ear-first" and "crowded room"

Tags: american-english, translation, slang

what does "enter crowded rooms" and "ear-first" mean in this sentence from the passage:

The paper’s eyes were big and round, whereas mine disappear altogether if
I smile, and my nose is more potatoey. That said, the spaces between my
features are in perfect proportion to each other. So far no one has noticed this.
Also my ears: darling little shells. I wear my hair tucked behind them and try
to enter crowded rooms ear-first, walking sideways. He drew a circle on the
paper’s throat and filled it in with careful cross-hatching.

Comment: What is your guess at what they mean? Both of these are being used quite literally. "ear-first" would probably make more sense if you look up "head-first" or "feet-first".

Comment: @katatahito I have no idea what that means, it's from Miranda July's novel and I can't understand

Comment: [enter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enter) [crowded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crowded) [room](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/room) ... for the first phrase which of the three words are unclear?

Comment: @katatahito ear-first means: with the ear in front of the rest of the body? (inspired by head-first meaning)  Is she hears things first in a metaphor way?

Comment: No, she is saying she literally walks into rooms with her ear being the first part of her head to enter. This is why she says she walks sideways. It is **strange** and **weird** to do this, which may be why you think it is metaphorical. In the sentence you are talking about she is listing 2 ways she shows off her ears: 1. tucking her hair behind them and 2. having them be the first thing someone sees when walking into a room

Comment: @katatahito WOW! Thank you! You helped me a lot.

Comment: Think about this: your ears **stick out** of your head so if you walk into a room sideways, one ear will enter it first, in terms of a part of your body.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments:

> "No, she is saying she literally walks into rooms with her ear being the first part of her head to enter. This is why she says she walks sideways. It is **strange** and **weird** to do this, which may be why you think it is metaphorical. In the sentence you are talking about she is listing 2 ways she shows off her ears: 1. tucking her hair behind them and 2. having them be the first thing someone sees when walking into a room" – katatahito Jul 18 at 7:13

and, "crowded room" is meant literally:

> [enter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enter) [crowded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crowded) [room](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/room) ... for the first phrase which of the three words are unclear? – katatahito Jul 18 at 6:52